# Why does the dependency resolver choose a version that should be explicitly forbidden (via !=)?

Tags: python, python-packaging

My project has a dependency that looks like:

```
avro-python3>=1.8.1,!=1.9.2,<1.10.0; python_version >= "3.0"
```

It's reflected like that on a line by itself in a `requirements.txt` file that I used as a basis for my project. I have this `pyproject.toml`, generated by PDM:

```ini
[tool.pdm]

[project]
# PEP 621 project metadata
# See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0621/
dependencies = ["apache-beam[gcp]>=2.16.0", "avro-python3!=1.9.2,<1.10.0,>=1.8.1; python_version >= \"3.0\"", "fastavro>=0.21.4", "Faker>=0.8.13", "faker-schema>=0.1.4", "google-cloud>=0.32", "google-cloud-bigquery>=1.1.0", "google-cloud-pubsub>=0.30.1", "google-cloud-storage>=1.6.0", "google-cloud-vision>=0.31.0", "google-resumable-media>=0.5.0", "mock<3.0.0,>=1.0.1", "numpy>=1.14.2", "pandas>=0.23.4", "scipy>=1.1.0", "httplib2<=0.12.0,>=0.8"]
requires-python = ">=3.8,<3.9"

[build-system]
requires = ["pdm-backend"]
build-backend = "pdm.backend"
```

This reflects that version `1.9.2` of `avro-python3` should be forbidden:

```ini
"avro-python3!=1.9.2,<1.10.0,>=1.8.1; python_version >= \"3.0\""
```

However, after I used PDM to resolve and install dependencies, it produced a lock file that shows that version `1.9.2.1` will be installed:

```
[[package]]
name = "avro-python3"
version = "1.9.2.1"
requires_python = ">=3.5"
summary = "Avro is a serialization and RPC framework."
```

Shouldn't this be prevented by `!=1.9.2` in the version specification? Doesn't that mean to forbid versions that start with `1.9.2`, such as `1.9.2.1`?

How can I specifically prevent the dependency resolver from using any of the `1.9.2` prefixed versions of the library, without making other restrictions?

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea about PDM, but would `!=1.9.2.*` work?

Comment: Yes, it did.  That resolved it to find `1.9.1`, which was OK.  I guess I should have thought of that, but it seems a bit fragile, since the author of a dependent package won't know a priori if there will be a division smaller than `PATCH`.

Comment: @AndrewMcClement with very little wiggle room (a few common extensions), build tools like PDM (also Flit, Poetry etc.) are implementing a standard. The question here isn't at all specific to the tool; I would expect any dependency resolver to do the same, because it's what the corresponding PEP says to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a requirement specification like `!=1.9.2` only excludes that *exact* version. Something like `!=1.9.2.*` should work. The complete standard rules for version matching are given in [PEP 440](https://peps.python.org/pep-0440/).

Some build tools offer a shorthand syntax `^` for version specifiers - where `^1.9.2` is shorthand for `>=1.9.2 <2.0.0` - but as shown that only stops at major version numbers (following semver, the expectation is that everything should be re-examined if a dependency moves to a such a version number). It also isn't designed to be used in the negative. The standard also includes `~=`, which behaves similarly.

The version specification scheme isn't designed to support forbidding arbitrary ranges of versions completely. (For example, it doesn't have an "or" operator, so it's not possible to apply De Morgan's laws by including the ranges before and after.) This seems likely intentional. The point of excluding versions is to signify that the *specific* version was tested and found not to work. If the dependency gets patched, that patch could very well be intended to fix the exact issue that caused the problem in the current project. It would not make sense, for example, to forbid everything from `1.9.2` up until `1.10` (or `2.0`) simply because a problem is discovered with `1.9.2`. That's against the spirit of why developers issue patch releases.

Comment: Is it worth mentioning (just for clarity) that 1.9.2.0 is considered equivalent to 1.9.2?

Comment: @AndrewMcClement probably, but offhand I'm not sure how to edit it in to have smooth prose. Feel free to give it a shot.